# Finialising the datatype of a input opearands on its actual bits used on embedded platform

Tags: c, algorithm, embedded, bit-manipulation, fixed-point

Generally when someone start porting the algorithms on some embedded platform, he /she has to figure out **how many bits require to store the results** and play around the bits and decide final data type (8 bit/16 bit/32 bit ). This is very important on embedded platform .

Now, I come across the same situation. But this is my first attempt to port my algorithm,But I Am not sure how I can start for below equation :

```
NOTE: Here pixel values are from 0 to 255 values .

...
uint32_t  shift = 11;
uint16_t val = some_val;
uint8_t pos = ((uint8_t) (val>>(shift-7))) & 0x7f;      

float t=(float)pos/(1<<7);

float res = (-1*t)*pixel[0] + (8-7*t)*pixel[1] + (7*t+1)*pixel[2] + (t-1)*pixel[3]/8 ;
```

So here below are the 4 operations in above equations:

```
(8-7*t)*pixel[1]
(7*t+1)*pixel[2]
(t-1)*pixel[3]/8
(-1*t)*pixel[0]
```

I want to understand, how I can represent the above floating point equation to fixed point format. Means if any one can guide me at least for the first operation `(8-7*t)*pixel[1]` for its handwritten fixed point format .

**Expectation:**

for example : (8-7*t)*pixel[1]

Here pixel values are from 0 to 255. Means `8 bit` `input` data type .

```
(8 - 7*t) =  (8 - 7 * 0.002) = (8 - 0.014 ) = 7.986 ..
```

so 7 can be represented in 3 bit and fraction bits extra .

I want to know this way .

I know everyone are busy in there work but If some one has little time for me to teach/guide me or provide me a link to learn to write the handwritten fixed point orations for such equation will be great . 
I am aware about the fixed point and floating point format .But I wants to know how the minimum bits are going to be used to represent the equation in fixed point format.

Comment: Is `0.001` the smallest value `t` can have?

Comment: `t` can have from `0.0 to 0.9`

Comment: Generally, to convert to fixed point, you multiply operands before applying division. If you need 4 digit resolution for example, you multiply with 1000, then divide, then use the result according to whatever unit you ended up with instead, mA instead of A or whatever. Start with specifying the expected value ranges of data, then pick large enough types accordingly.

Comment: @jailaxmik What is the minimum increment of `t`?

Comment: @FiddlingBits,Now I have updated my post with some more details .

Comment: @Lundin,I understood little bit from this .As I am first time porting .So not able to visualize what you mentioned .Can you please give me example in your answer's post.So I can understand this better .Sorry for that .

Comment: Instead of `float t=(float)pos/(1<<7);` maybe you can use `uint8_t = pos`.  After using `t`, in `(-1*t)*pixel[0]`, for example, you can divide result by `(1<<7)`.  You would lose precision but you could avoid using floating point.

Comment: @FiddlingBits,If possible can you tell me what will be the impact of using `pos` instead of `t ` on other remaining 3 operations ??